# Cannot delete folder created through python os.mkdir

Tags: python

I have an issue with folders created through a Python script that cannot be removed.

I have a python script that runs other scripts using the 'runpy' module. The scripts will then create a folder using os.mkdir and a lot of matplotlib figures will be saved in there. When the script has run, and I try to delete the folder, I'm not allowed.

Through os.listdir the folder will show up:

```
In[5]: import os
       'aux' in os.listdir(r'C:\Python\Repositories\model-enveloper\Test')
Out[5]: True
```

But trying to delete the folder with os.rmdir (not possible through windows explorer either):

```
In[6]: os.rmdir(r'C:\Python\Repositories\model-enveloper\Test\aux')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-c835caa088bf>", line 1, in <module>
    os.rmdir(r'C:\Python\Repositories\model-enveloper\Test\aux')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python\\Repositories\\model-enveloper\\Test\\aux'
```

Comment: Did you try `os.rmdir(r'C:/Python/Repositories/model-enveloper/Test/aux')`?

Comment: the error says that the folder is not found, not that you're not allowed to delete it. Also, `rmdir` should raise `OSError` if the directory is not empty (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.rmdir)).

Comment: The folder is empty and I did also try all sorts of combinations of "\" and "/". No luck. You are correct, the error is that it cannot find it - but it only cannot find it when I try to delete it. It does find the folder with os.listdir (and I can see it in explorer).

Comment: strange... did you try to run the command from `cmd`? just to make sure it's not an `ipython` issue

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred because of these reasons.

1. You need to give admin permission to delete that directory.
2. `rmdir` use for to delete **Empty directories**. make sure your mentioned directory is empty. If it is true use `shutil.rmtree(<directory>)` to remove directry with contents.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("<directory>")
```

3. Try `C:/Python/Repositories/model-enveloper/Test/aux` instead of `C:\Python\Repositories\model-enveloper\Test\aux` @Bakuriu has mentioned it.

There for you can try to delete it like this

```
import os
os.rmdir(os.path.join("C:/Python/Repositories/model-enveloper/Test", "aux"))
```

Comment: 1. I don't think it's an admin issue as I cannot delete it through explorer either and I have no problems with other folders. It seems that the folder is somehow defective (e.g. security information in explorer>properties are unavailable). 2. The folder is empty, but did also just try shutil.rmtree without any luck. 3. Tried many combinations "\" and "/".

Comment: use only "/". by the way what is your current directry.

Comment: Yes, I did try with only "/" - just like your last snip of code.

Comment: How did you create aux directory.

Comment: I have a python script that runs other scripts using the 'runpy' module. The scripts will then create a folder using os.mkdir and a lot of matplotlib figures will be saved in there.

Comment: I mean what code did you use to create aux directory?

Comment: `path='C:/Python/Repositories/model-enveloper/Test'
if 'plots' not in os.listdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path + '/plots')`

Comment: I think you have to add your full code to your question. edit your question and add it.

Comment: you have created plots directory then you need to delete aux